# Perl script to generate sip calls and record

Tags: automation, sip, perl-module

I'm looking for perl script to generate sip calls and record each sip calls (to calculate the PESQ value later) other than SIPp.

What are the possible automations we can develop using perl to test sip client application?

Thanks,
Vallikkv

Comment: This question is too open-ended.  Perhaps if you explain why SIPp doesn't do what you want?

Comment: I really dont know how to record the audio in the recieving end to calculate PESQ. And i came to know NET:SIP perl CPAN module can be used for sip call. If i use perl, i have the full control and using script, it's easy for me to generate call and calcualte PESQ,MOS values for each call and also to create a report.